# Monodroid Hello World opens and just closes?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to get the "Hello world" droid application to run in the emulator. The applicaiton icon shows in the Apps of the emulator but when I press it it opens but no buttons and no hello world. I am using the code as is from the site. This occurs in both MonoDeveloper and VS 2010 w/ plug-in. Also the same thing happens when I use an associates applicaiton... It just opens and then closes?
Any help would be great. I am using VS 2010 professional, windows 7 64bit.
Thanks,
Charles

Comment: Can you provide the debug log output? http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log

Answer (score 0):

If it opens and then closes without a screeen display, It may mean that you have a run time error.  Check out each line for typo's